# Can't get indentation by filetype to work in Vim

Tags: c#, vim

I'm trying to get indentation with spaces to work in C# files, and I can't get it to work.

This is the relevant part of my ~/.vim/ftplugin/cs.vim:

```
" Indent with 4 spaces
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

I've tried placing that in ~/.vim/indent/cs.vim, ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cs.vim,
I've tried using setlocal instead of the two, and `filetype plugin indent` is on.

I've tried with `autocmd FileType cs setlocal shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab`.
I've also tried moving the tabs configuration around in my .vimrc.
When I change the configuration in .vimrc it works for other files, but even if I remove the tab configuration from ~/.vim/ftplugin/cs.vim it still doesn't work in C# files.

This is my .vimrc

```
" Plugins
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin'
Plug 'tomtom/tcomment_vim'
Plug 'wincent/Command-T', { 'do': 'cd ruby/command-t/ext/command-t && ruby extconf.rb && make' }
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': 'python install.py --cs-completer --clang-completer --java-completer' }
Plug 'milkypostman/vim-togglelist'
Plug 'vimwiki/vimwiki'
Plug 'jreybert/vimagit'
call plug#end()

" Don't highlight on search
set nohlsearch

" Search while typing
set incsearch

" Disable mouse navigation
set mouse=""

" Set nocompatible vi mode
set nocompatible

" Set unix fileformat
set fileformat=unix

" Automatically change dir to current file
set autochdir

" Hide buffers when abandoned
set hidden

" Backspace through everythin
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" Filetype plugin on and indent by filetype
filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on

" Syntax highlighting
syntax on

" Set autoindent
set autoindent

" Indent with mixed tabs and spaces
set shiftwidth=8
set softtabstop=8

" Colorscheme
colorscheme monokai
highlight Normal ctermbg=None
highlight LineNr ctermbg=None
highlight NonText ctermbg=None
highlight CursorLineNR ctermfg=None ctermbg=None

" Folding
set foldmethod=syntax

" Remember folds
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview

" Encoding
set encoding=utf-8

" Show relative line numbers and the current line number
set number relativenumber

" Always show status line
set laststatus=2

" Always show at least two fiveline above and below the cursor
set scrolloff=2

" Always show at least five columns right and left of the cursor
set sidescrolloff=5

" Show a ruler at 80 characters and at 120+ characters
let &colorcolumn="80,".join(range(120,999),",")
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=235

" Vim autocomplete
set wildmode=list:longest

" Set display to show as much as possible of a long last line
set display=lastline

" Disable automatic comment insertion
autocmd FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o

" Remove trailing whitespace on write
autocmd BufWritePre * %s/\s\+$//e

" Split to the right and below
set splitright splitbelow

" Set shell
set shell=/usr/bin/env\ bash

" Automatically read file if the file was changed in the background
set autoread

" Max lines in history
set history=1000

" Max number of tab pages
set tabpagemax=50

" Set default tex flavor to latex
let g:tex_flavor = "latex"

" Set <leader> and <localleader>
let mapleader="\\"
let maplocalleader="\\"

" Save as sudo command
command SW :w !sudo tee %

" Bind :Q to :q
command Q :q

" Open bash
map <C-t> :sh<CR>

" Copy to clipboard shortcut
nnoremap <C-c> "+y

" Map fuzzy file finder to CTRL+P
map <C-p> \t

" Spell check
nnoremap <localleader>o :set spell! spelllang=en_us,hr_hr<CR>

" Shortcuts for split navigation
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>

" Nerdtree toggle shortcut
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Vimagit shortcut
map <C-g> :Magit<CR>

" Provide a default YCM file to YouCompleteMe
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = "~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py"

" Options for YouCompleteMe syntax checking
let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 1
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 0
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_highlighting = 1
let g:ycm_always_populate_location_list = 1
let g:ycm_open_loclist_on_ycm_diags = 1

" Vimwiki options
let g:vimwiki_autowriteall = 0
```

I'm not sure where the problem is, or what else to try.
Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question.

I used `:verbose set shiftwidth` to see where the variable was last set, and as it turns out, it was my views.

After deleting every view from `~/.vim/views/`, changing the settings worked.